# Running PostgreSQL commands in other language

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to force PostgreSQL commands (`pg_ctl`, `postgres`, `initdb`, etc.) to run in English and not honor the system locale? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set locale related environment variables (LC_LANG, LC_ALL etc) during command execution:

```
LC_ALL=locale_name command_name
```

E.g.

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 postgres
```